# Dart rounding errors

Tags: dart

So doing a `print(0.3 - 0.2);` will print `0.09999999999999998`.

I know floating point arithmetic is impossible for a binary processor to get correct, but I was hoping for something built into Dart that would at least try to kill off the rounding errors.

Getting the above to show 0.1 takes some conversions back and forth, which I'd rather not do:

```
print(num.parse((0.3 - 0.2).toStringAsPrecision(8)));

-> 0.1
```

What are my options for not going crazy working with decimals? Is there anything built into Dart to help with this? There seems to be only one library that does the above: https://pub.dev/packages/decimal?

Comment: Aside: never do money math with floating point.  Remember _Superman IV_ and _Office Space_. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can round a value to a multiple of ten (or of any other number) by:

```
double roundTo(double value, double precision) => (value * precision).round() / precision;
```

You can then do that to either the initial values or the final result:

```
int precision = 10;
final result = roundTo(0.3 - 0.2, precision);
// or inlined:
final result = ((0.3 - 0.2) * precision).round() / precision;
```

This ensures that the computation is done on the original values, and you only round the final result.

If you know that your input values all have the same scale, you can do as @brian-gorman suggests and scale the values first, and then round and down-scale the result at the end. For that use, I would recommend rounding early, on the incoming values, so that the computation will not accumulate imprecision.
(That doesn't matter for a single subtraction, but for a more complicated computation, it might).

```
final difference = (0.3 * precision).round() - (0.2 * precision).round();
final result = difference / precision;
```

For the record: The result you are seeing is not a rounding error, it is the *correct* result—for 64-bit floating point numbers as defined by IEEE-754.

You will see the *same* result in any other language using normal doubles, including JavaScript and Java. The result of `0.3 - 0.2` *is not* the double represented as `0.1`. It is a different number, so it must have a different `toString` representation.

Neither of 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 can be represented exactly as doubles. The actual values are:

- `0.1` : 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
- `0.2` : 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
- `0.3` : 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
- `0.3 - 0.2` : 0.09999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375

So when you write the *syntax* `0.3` and `0.2`, you are really specifying the precise double values above.

The result becomes what it is because the precise mathematical calculation of 0.3 - 0.2 is

```
  0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
- 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125 
= 0.099999999999999977795539507496869191527366638183593750
```

and the result is an exact double value. So the result 0.09999... is precisely the difference between "0.3" and "0.2" and therefore the correct result for the subtraction. (The mistake is assuming that you actually have 0.3 and 0.2 as values, you never did). It is also *not* the same as the number represented by 0.1.

Comment: Thanks for the expansive answer. Can you clarify what you mean by `0.0999999` being the *correct* result?

Comment: I appreciate the tip of rounding early. In a previous project, we struggled to kill off rounding errors that had snuck in, and were hard to get rid off. Tbh. I still refer to them as rounding errors and not imprecision, because when a human writes 0.3 - 0.2, the underlying assumption is that the values written, are the values that are being computed, and not the underlying IEEE-754 representation. Still it's valuable to know what happens under the hood, in order to make better decisions. Anyway, thank you very much for the great answer!

Comment: Whether something is a rounding *error* is probably a philosophical discussion. Arguably the language rounds `0.2` to the nearest double value, and you could consider that an error. Or you could also define that the syntax `0.2` denotes that double value, and it's a (human assumption) mistake to assume that it is the mathematical value 2/10. Potatoh, potahto, the result is the same, and we poor humans are only here to instruct the computer what to do. The computer is always right by definition, it's just the instructions that may be for the wrong thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

What most people do is multiply, do math, round, then divide by the desired precision

```
final precision = 10;


final difference = (0.3 * precision) - (0.2 * precision);
final result = difference.round() / precision; // will give you 0.1
```

The `.round()` ensures that any trailing decimals after math gets rounded off before you return to the desired precision.